# Merge main Observable stream with updates

Tags: rxjs

I need to merge main stream with updates stream this way:

```
Main:  ----A-------B-------------C---|--
Upd:   -D-----E---------F---G--------|--
========================================
Result:----A--AE---B----BF--BG---C---|--
```

I.e., when **Main** emitted, the result should always be **Main** (or **Main** with empty **Upd**). When **Upd** was emitted without previous **Main**, it should be ignored. If **Upd** was emitted after **Main**, then they should be combined.

Consider this TypeScript code:

```js
interface Item {
  Id: number;
  Data: string;
}

function mergeUpdates(main: Item[], upd: Item[]) {
  if (!upd || upd.length === 0) {
      return main;
    }
    const result = main;
    // const result = {...main};
    for (const updatedItem of upd) {
      const srcIndex = result.findIndex(_ => _.Id === updatedItem.Id);
      if (srcIndex >= 0) {
        result[srcIndex] = updatedItem;
      } else {
        result.push(updatedItem);
      }
    }
    return result;
}

const main$ = new Subject<Item[]>();
const upd$ = new Subject<Item[]>();

const result$ = combineLatest(main$, upd$).pipe( // combineLatest is wrong operator!
  map(([main, upd]) => mergeUpdates(main, upd)));

$result.subscribe(r => console.log(r.map(_ => _.Data).join(',')));

main$.next([{Id:1, Data:'Data1'}, {Id:2, Data:'Data2'}]);
upd$.next([{Id:1, Data:'Updated1'}]);
upd$.next([{Id:1, Data:'Updated2'}]);
main$.next([{Id:1, Data:'Data1_Orig'}, {Id:2, Data:'Data2'}]);

// Expexted result:
// 'Data1,Data2'
// 'Updated1,Data2'
// 'Updated2,Data2'
// 'Data1_Orig,Data2'
```

The only solution I have in mind is to use 'combineLatest' and mark items in **upd$** stream as processed, thus do not use it again when data from **main$** emitted later. I believe this is not the best approach as it cause unwanted side effects.

Is there any better solution for this task?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here would be my approach:

```js
main$.pipe(
    switchMap(
        mainValue => merge(
            of(mainValue),
            upd$.pipe(
                map(updVal => mainValue + updVal)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

`switchMap` - make sure the inner observable's emitted values will be *combined* with the latest outer value

`merge(of(a), upd$.pipe())` - emit the *main* value first, then listen to any notifications `upd$` emits and combine them with the current *main* value

If another outer value comes in, the inner subscriber will be unsubscribed, meaning that the `upd` subject won't have redundant subscribers.

Comment: This is brilliant! I've modified code for my needs a bit: 
const result$ = main$.pipe(
   switchMap(
       main => upd$.pipe(
          startWith(undefined),
          map(upd => mergeUpdates(main, upd))));

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful!